# EXIM debugging option "debug_print" unknown

Tags: centos, exim

How do you get exim on centos to debug?

option "debug_print" unknown ("driver" must be specified before any private options)

```
remote_login:
  debug_print = "This is a test"
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = LOGIN
  client_send = : user : password
```

sudo service exim restart

> Starting exim: 2017-03-29 11:13:41 Exim configuration error in line 2
>   of /etc/exim/remote_login_auth: option "debug_print" unknown ("driver"
>   must be specified before any private options)

or

sudo exim -d

> LOG: PANIC DIE
>     Exim configuration error in line 2 of /etc/exim/remote_login_auth:
>     option "debug_print" unknown ("driver" must be specified before any private options)

Comment: I added some tips for debugging exim in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because `debug_print` is not a valid option for an *authenticator*, which appears to be what you are configuring.  `debug_print` is a *transport* option.

---

**Tips for debugging exim**

- Test your configuration without restarting exim:  `exim -bV`
- Test how exim will route a given address: `exim -bh 192.168.254.170`
- Trace a pretend SMTP transaction: `exim -bt alias@localdomain.com`

Ref: [Exim Cheatsheet](http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/exim_cheatsheet.php)

Answer (score 0):

> "driver" must be specified before any private options

i.e.

```
remote_login:
  driver = plaintext
  debug_print = "This is a test"
  public_name = LOGIN
  client_send = : user : password
```